# Skip certain lines only in one file while reading multiple files simultaneously

Tags: python

I have two files like so:

```
File1:
Apple
Banana
Orange
Pineapple

File2:
Apple
Banana
Pineapple
```

I want to read both files simultaneously, but when I see `orange` in File1, I want to skip that line ONLY IN FILE1 and go to the next line. Is there a way to do that in python?

So far I have tried:

```
with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2:
    f1_f2 = itertools.izip(f1,f2)
    line1,line2 = f1_f2.next()
```

But I don't know where to go from there.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: If I understand you correct, that is easy to do in Python. Do you want to skip any line that says `Orange` or just the first? What if the line begins with `Orange` but has more text? More important, what work have you done on this problem, and just where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as file2:
    line1 = file1.readline().strip()  # read line, and remove newline character at end
    line2 = file1.readline().strip()
    while(line1 == "Orange"):
        line1 = file1.readline()
    ...
```

Put this structure inside a loop - when `readline()` returns `''` is when the file is empty. You could also use `readlines()` instead of `readline()` and then iterate through the resulting list however you like.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the files are in current directory:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir():
    with open(filename,"r") as data:
        file_contents = data.readlines()
    if filename = "File1":
        file_contents.remove("Orange\n")
    #work with file contents
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, please update question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip_longest` and use `next` to skip line

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import zip_longest

with open(filename) as file_1, open(filename2) as file_2:
    for m, n in zip_longest(file_1, file_2, fillvalue=""):
        if m.strip() == "Orange":
            m = next(file_1)
        print(m.strip(), n.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Apple Apple
Banana Banana
Pineapple Pineapple
```